# Estimate the likelihood of two continuous samples of unknown distribution

Tags: distributions, nonparametric, likelihood, empirical-likelihood

Consider two continuous and unknown distributions

$$X : {x_1, x_2, ..., x_n}$$

and

$$Y : {y_1, y_2, ..., y_n}$$

both can be tagged as time series with $n > 8000$.

I need to estimate the likelihood of the observations in $X$ for $Y$ in a non-parametric manner. So far, I am estimating $G$ (the empirical PDF of $Y$) and I evaluate the density at each $x_i$. Resulting the likelihood of $X$ for $Y$ something like this:
$$L = \sum_{i=1}^n G(x_i)$$
As you can see, I am far from an expert in probabilistic statistics.

- Is this approach correct? If not, could you please provide an approach to solve it by means of pseudocode, python or R?
- Should I use an empirical PDF (density calculated by binning following thumb up rules like Sturge) or I should evaluate the density by means of a KDE?